# union of 2 tables without duplicates

Tags: sql, join, union

I'm having a bit of a hard time finding a clear answer on this. 
I have 2 tables with exactly the same columns, lets say t1 & t2. 
I want to add to t1 all the rows from t2 but eliminate duplicates in the final t1.

I can use SELECT INTO but that will leave me with duplicates from what I understand. at the moment I used simple UNION (which eliminates duplicates) into a new table t3, but that makes everything a bit messy since I need to keep all the rows in t1 in the end (so I did "DROP TABLE t1 and rename t3 to t1"). but I'm thinking, there's got to be a better way to do this, maybe with one of the JOINS?

Comment: I don't need it to be ordered

Comment: but I need to save the result in a table, not just return the result of the union query

Comment: Sample data and desired results would clarify the question.  What do you mean by duplicate?  Absent other information, one would assume all the columns.  Hence, `UNION` would be a correct approach.

Comment: yes, UNION would work, but how can I use UNION of t1 & t2 and save the result in t1 (not just return the union)?

Answer (score 1):

Just do an `INSERT` where the values don't already exist in the first table:

```
Insert Into T1 (Col1, Col2, ...)
Select  T2.Col1, T2.Col2, ...
From    T2  
Where Not Exists
(
    Select  *
    From    T1
    Where   (T1.Col1 = T2.Col1 Or (T1.Col1 Is Null And T2.Col1 Is Null))
    And     (T1.Col2 = T2.Col2 Or (T1.Col2 Is Null And T2.Col2 Is Null))
    And     ...
)
```

Comment: @lad2025 Fair point about the `NULL`s, but I'm not so sure on the second point.  From the question: `I want to add to t1 all the rows from t2 but eliminate duplicates in the final t1.`  It sounds to me like all he wants to do is insert the new records from `t2` to `t1` without duplicating rows.

Comment: Updated for `NULL` conditions in the data.

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO T1 (column1, column2, column3,...columnN) 
(SELECT column1, column2, column3,...columnN FROM T2
EXCEPT
SELECT column1, column2, column3,...columnN FROM T1)
```